# Trying to match script tags in html with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the following html snipped and regular expression, trying to match all of the script tags that do not have 'data-capture="0"' attribute.

```
$html = '
 <p>
    <script src="//test.com/should-be-matched-but-it-is-not-library.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//test.com/should-not-be-matched-but-it-is-library.js" data-capture="0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//test.com/correctly-matched-library.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var foo = "correctly matched";</script>
    <script>var bar = "correctly matched again";</script>
    <script data-capture="0">var baz= "correctly not be matched";</script>
    <script src="//test.com/correctly-not-matched-library.js" data-capture="0"></script>
 </p>
';
preg_match_all('/((<script(?: type="text\/javascript"(?! data-capture="0")).*?>|<script>).*?<\/script>)/s', $html, $matches);
```

However, the first script is not matched (should be) and the second is (shouldn't) and I cannot figure why. Can someone give a suggestion ?

I am aware that regular expressions are not reliable when parsing HTML. Let's view it as a general regular expression case, not as attempt to create a HTML parser.

Comment: Obligatory "you can't parse HTML with a regular expression": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I know it's bad to parse HTML with regex. Let's assume this is just a special case and I am aware of the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this way:

```
preg_match_all(
     '/((<script(?! data-capture="0").*?>|<script>).*?<\/script>)/s',
     $html, 
     $matches
);
```

The first one doesn't have type attribute, while you are searching for it in the regular expression

Comment: I modified my original questions with more tests and your suggestion matches the second script, but shouldn't